# Naming New Tab with Image

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to rename a new tab I am opening up. This new tab contains an `iframe` with an image as the source. This is how I am opening the tab, but can't seem to get `document.title` to work.

```
var customTab = window.open();
customTab && customTab.document.title = 'My new tab';//this doesn't work
customTab &&
  customTab.document.write(
    '<iframe src="' +
      myImage +
      '" style="border: none;"></iframe>'
  );
```

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you should try this:

```js
var customTab = window.open();
customTab.onload = function() {
  customTab.document.title = 'My new tab';
  customTab.document.write(
    '<iframe src="' + myImage + '" style="border: none;"></iframe>'
  );
};
```

The issue with setting the `document.title` in your code is likely due to the fact that the content of the newly opened window is dynamically generated with an `iframe`, and the `document.title` might not be accessible immediately after the `window.open()` call.

Comment: This should fix your issue

Comment: If it doesn't, please let me know, and I will try to find another solution!

Answer (score 0):

replace `customTab && customTab.document.title = 'My new tab';`

with `if (customTab) customTab.document.title = 'My new tab';`

You can't assign a value to a variable inside an `&&` expression